# Is there any way to input in Python that is analogous to simple input in Java using Scanner class?

Tags: python, input

I am new to python and had a problem, wherein input from the online judge is supposed to be in the form] of a horizontal row of integers.
I am trying to store them as a list.
input format: 5 4 4 2 2 8
But every time I type in horizontal row of characters I get the error :
        unexpected EOF while parsing

Is there a way to do it in Python like there is Scanner class in python that easily inputs various data type.

Edit: It will be really helpful if you can tell how do we differentiate which data type is input by the user for the input above can easily considered a String.

Answer (score 0):

A convenient way to read input from `stdin` when using online judges is to iterate through the input lines like this:

```
for line in sys.stdin:
    inp_array = line.split() # split the line
    a = int(inp-array[0])
    b = float(inp_array[1])
```

This would result in that the input `3 2.5` is read into the variables `a` and `b`

When getting user input through `stdin` the best way is to use the `input()` method. This returns a string that you then can try to convert to whatever datatype you want (and handle the error if what the user provided isn't of the type you expected)